# Current status of support, on 12.10 quantal, for intel optimus?

Tags: thinkpad, nvidia-optimus, 12.10, vga, hybrid-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Which is the current status of the support, on 12.10, for intel optimus?

I've seen lots of talk around, but how does it translate into practical support?

I have a Thinkpad W520, which has the VGA output hardwired to the nvidia card, and a bios option for switching the two cards.
I was hoping to be able to enable the nvidia card and use the VGA output (and viceversa, disable it and use the laptop screen) without restarting the machine.

Comment: Also look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work